# Dell Precision 7510 external monitor

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, dell, nvidia-optimus, vgaswitcheroo

Has anyone managed to get some version of Ubuntu working well on a Dell Precision 7510?

I have tried 14.04 and 15.10. The latter works ok, except for graphics. I am running on the Intel integrated, using i915 driver. It flickers occasionally, and when I attach an external monitor, most KDE applications crash. It seems to be the case that it tries to switch to the Nvidia card, but fails.

If I disable hybrid graphics in BIOS, the screen is black. I have tried both Nouveau and Nvidia drivers (up to 352).

To anyone considering a Precision 7510 for running Ubuntu: Beware that although this page claims it is supported, it is not: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/SupportedOS/precision-m7510-workstation. Dell is bouncing off my support requests, directing me to the community, and will not refund the pro support cost. I'll revert to Lenovo next time.

Comment: This worked for me under 15.10, but after an upgrade to 16.04 LTS, it no longer works. http://askubuntu.com/questions/789972/add-secondary-monitor-nvidia-367-27-16-04-displayport